# Computer Crashes and then has difficulty rebooting

Tags: macos, hardware, crash, kernel-panic

My MBP Retina, Early 2013 15" is having some problems. Last week it crashed on me and wouldn't boot, only the fans would start spinning and heat was produced but no reaction on the screen, or an external screen. It wouldn't go into recovery or safe mode, but could do a PRAM reset (double chime). The technician diagnosed the keyboard connector to the logic board as faulty, repaired it and it booted up again and worked decently well. This was two days ago. Today, the computer crashed two more times, and the second time I could only reboot it through recovery mode. I have pasted an excerpt of the most recent crash report below, they were all similar. Does anyone have any idea what is still wrong, I know this is a very open ended question but can provide more details I havent thought to mention if there are any questions. Thanks!

EDIT: Updated the crash report and also, the last time it gave me problems I received the following message:[image: Panic media boot]

```
Crash Report:


Fri Mar 13 18:21:18 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff7fa4e6c8d3): "GPU Panic: mux-regs 5 0 a0 d9 9 8 severity 3 WS-ready 1 switch-state 5 IG FBs 1 EG FBs 1:f power-state 0 3D idle HDA idle system-state 1 power-level 20:20 connect-change 0 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x0011e598: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xc0000000 0xffffff91495ae000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P1/4\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.20.17/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:170
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff812fb0aba0 : 0xffffff802366ce56 
0xffffff812fb0abf0 : 0xffffff80237963e4 
0xffffff812fb0ac30 : 0xffffff80237885b4 
0xffffff812fb0aca0 : 0xffffff802361ee60 
0xffffff812fb0acc0 : 0xffffff802366c8cc 
0xffffff812fb0adf0 : 0xffffff802366c68c 
0xffffff812fb0ae50 : 0xffffff7fa4e6c8d3 
0xffffff812fb0aeb0 : 0xffffff7fa42f6f05 
0xffffff812fb0af30 : 0xffffff7fa43c4e19 
0xffffff812fb0af90 : 0xffffff7fa6543f79 
0xffffff812fb0afd0 : 0xffffff7fa653fdda 
0xffffff812fb0b010 : 0xffffff7fa64c9520 
0xffffff812fb0b230 : 0xffffff7fa64bb87e 
0xffffff812fb0b2d0 : 0xffffff7fa64bbcc5 
0xffffff812fb0b330 : 0xffffff7fa430d591 
0xffffff812fb0b380 : 0xffffff7fa64c0534 
0xffffff812fb0b4e0 : 0xffffff7fa64c0b4a 
0xffffff812fb0b570 : 0xffffff7fa431032c 
0xffffff812fb0b5a0 : 0xffffff7fa44009b9 
0xffffff812fb0b610 : 0xffffff7fa4400531 
0xffffff812fb0b640 : 0xffffff7fa4411645 
0xffffff812fb0b700 : 0xffffff7fa42cee65 
0xffffff812fb0b760 : 0xffffff7fa42ce254 
0xffffff812fb0b780 : 0xffffff7fa42cdebc 
0xffffff812fb0b830 : 0xffffff7fa42cdca2 
0xffffff812fb0b850 : 0xffffff7fa42bbcae 
0xffffff812fb0b8f0 : 0xffffff7fa42fb7f4 
0xffffff812fb0ba70 : 0xffffff7fa42fc365 
0xffffff812fb0bb70 : 0xffffff7fa44d1a4f 
0xffffff812fb0bbc0 : 0xffffff7fa44d25cd 
0xffffff812fb0bcc0 : 0xffffff7fa428c643 
0xffffff812fb0bd50 : 0xffffff7fa426ffef 
0xffffff812fb0bdc0 : 0xffffff7fa4272ff9 
0xffffff812fb0be00 : 0xffffff7fa41129da 
0xffffff812fb0be50 : 0xffffff7fa4112568 
0xffffff812fb0be80 : 0xffffff7fa4119025 
0xffffff812fb0bed0 : 0xffffff8023c99d95 
0xffffff812fb0bf30 : 0xffffff8023c98502 
0xffffff812fb0bf70 : 0xffffff8023c97b2c 
0xffffff812fb0bfa0 : 0xffffff802361e557 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.20.17)[A9D09AAA-5C21-3603-A9AD-2FF7D3305A12]@0xffffff7fa4e5e000->0xffffff7fa4e70fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.20.17)[5DFE15FC-E7D4-3D71-AD86-38B4EC900DC8]@0xffffff7fa4e2f000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[95DA39BB-7C39-3742-A2E5-86C555E21D67]@0xffffff7fa499c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[5A070389-F327-3542-96C3-D2E795B4FE0A]@0xffffff7fa3e94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.23)[81D774E8-DD11-3866-B90A-E855215EDB60]@0xffffff7fa4108000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.20.17)[253B3260-1884-3A3C-BD18-3D251DADB77F]@0xffffff7fa427e000
         com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(519.21)[B9EB0174-55E4-3CB1-9802-E74BB1BD5EF0]@0xffffff7fa426e000->0xffffff7fa427dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.23)[81D774E8-DD11-3866-B90A-E855215EDB60]@0xffffff7fa4108000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[5A070389-F327-3542-96C3-D2E795B4FE0A]@0xffffff7fa3e94000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.3.2)[6DE4BC26-EEC1-379B-AD41-532FB0A529CD]@0xffffff7fa428a000->0xffffff7fa4563fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[5A070389-F327-3542-96C3-D2E795B4FE0A]@0xffffff7fa3e94000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(519.21)[B9EB0174-55E4-3CB1-9802-E74BB1BD5EF0]@0xffffff7fa426e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.23)[81D774E8-DD11-3866-B90A-E855215EDB60]@0xffffff7fa4108000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.20.17)[253B3260-1884-3A3C-BD18-3D251DADB77F]@0xffffff7fa427e000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(10.3.2)[60E264DA-1FBB-37D2-A834-8A15DBD562D3]@0xffffff7fa6491000->0xffffff7fa663efff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.3.2)[6DE4BC26-EEC1-379B-AD41-532FB0A529CD]@0xffffff7fa428a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[5A070389-F327-3542-96C3-D2E795B4FE0A]@0xffffff7fa3e94000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
17G11023

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jan 23 07:05:23 PST 2020; root:xnu-4570.71.69~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: D8347098-9B31-3C8E-A1C9-CA857F05BB97
Kernel slide:     0x0000000023400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8023600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8023500000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 95183521867
last loaded kext at 33476429017: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 6.0.12 (addr 0xffffff7fa7017000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.0.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.0.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.0.12
com.kairos.driver.DuetDisplay   2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.0.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.20.17
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   281.52
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.GeForce   10.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f17
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.20.17
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.6
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.3.2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.7f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.21.30
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1250.20.1a4
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   186
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 683.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.3.2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.21
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.17
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.28
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.17
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.23
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.5.5
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.7f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 262
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.9
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please [edit] your question to include the complete crash report.  See [ask] for info on how to ask questions on this site.

Comment: What system are you running on your Mac.

Comment: @fsb How do I pull up an old crash report, I closed the window after copying the part that looked interesting (sorry!) But now I'm not sure where to find it again in the console.

Comment: @jmh It's high sierra (10.13.6)

Comment: The tech didn’t fix your problem. Did you try [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold `D` while booting).  The crash report is way to short for anything useful; however I’m curious, are you using an external display?

Comment: @Allan The Diagnostics seem to not be working but this is a common problem it seems. I am not using an external display, currently the built-in one works. I will add crash report the next time it crashes. The error from the diagnostics is: Error: 800000000000000, Cannot load 'EFI/Drivers/TestSupport.efi' Status 0x00000003.

Comment: I added the full crash report of the most recent shutdown. I feel like it may have something to do with the graphics. Any help continues to be appreciated.

Comment: You can try uninstalling virtual box, just for testing. (it will remove its kernel extensions) It could be interfering with graphics drivers. You can always install back if you  need

Comment: @ankii I just uninstalled it. I also had a Cisco Anyconnect client for VPN which I now de-installed as it is always prompting for permission. Hopefully this will fix it. I will continue updating here.

Comment: The message you got said it’s 3rd party software causing your issues. Try booting in Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting). Do the problems go away?